# What are the main differences between a Metasploit vulnerability/exploit attack and a "R.A.T." attack?

Tags: attacks, metasploit, vulnerability, remote-desktop

I explain myself: To attack with a vulnerability & exploit it with Metasploit, you have first to find a vulnerability listed. Then once you have it, you set up the whole thing and end up with a link with the malicious file in it (to be clicked on).

So my question is: why someone would bother doing this, if he can attain the same results by getting control with a R.A.T. (downloadable through a link to be clicked on, too). 
With a RAT, you wouldn't have to bother searching for proper exploit.
And in both cases, you have to escape the anti-virus.
Can someone explain me this please ?

Answer (score 5):

I think you are confusing a couple of different ideas. Metasploit helps you leverage *vulnerabilities* in order to craft *exploits*. Those exploits are used to deliver *payloads*. The resulting code can be something the user needs to install, or Metasploit can allow you to deliver the exploit directly without the user being involved (depending on the vulnerability).

The payload sent by the exploit can be many things, one of which is a RAT (called Meterpreter in Metasploit). But it can also be other kinds of payloads.

The scenario you describe for a RAT does not require an exploit or a vulnerability: you suggest the user just clicks on the malware and runs it. For that, you do not need the resources of Metasploit at all, although Metasploit could be helpful by providing the Meterpreter and the control hub.

Comment: Yes, so why someone would "bother" looking for vulnerabilities (and making sure they fit the configuration of the victim) to be able to deliver a paypload when he can do the same thing directly with a R.A.T.? 
In both cases, the victim will have to click on something; and in both cases, you will have to make it undetectable to AV. 
But in one case, you have to search/consult and use vulnerabilities, adding one more step to the whole process.  

PS: by "R.A.T.", I mean the software like "Cyabergate", "NJrat" etc...

Comment: If there are two files: employee_salary.exe and employee_salary.xls. Which file would bypass the firewall/IDS/IPS/, host based access control, email filtering policy etc? And which one would you click? That's why you need vulnerabilities in order to exploit a particular application while remaining stealthy. If you check a typical enterprise security policy, a lot of times executable code is restricted based upon publisher details, trusted locations etc while MS Office and PDFs can operate freely.

Comment: @Nick Not all vulnerabilities require user interaction to exploit. If your goal is encouraging the user to run a file, then that's more social engineering than exploitation. If your goal is exploiting a flaw in the user's OS or running services, which can usually be achieved without any user interaction, metasploit is the way to go.

Comment: @void_in: But you can change the icon of a RAT. Or you can bind it with something else (a pdf).

Comment: @Nick: So the (only?) reason of using vulnerabilities attacks would be that RAT always need the victim to click ? And Metasploit, in some cases, doesn't need any clicking and interaction with the victim ?
Unlike RAT, Metasploit's exploits always need victim's computer configuration, right ? If you don't have an IP or another information (adobe version etc...), you can't perform any exploit ? That the downside, am I correct ?

Comment: @Nick Changing the icon has nothing to do with file types. IDS/IPS, AV, file type filtering etc don't take decisions based upon a file icon. User interaction is dependent on the type of application or service you are exploiting. If you are exploiting a core Windows service that listens remotely and which the attacker can interact with (e.g. SMB Server service), you don't need interaction. If you are exploiting word.exe, you require interaction since word.exe don't listen and can't be interacted with remotely.

Comment: @Nick Metasploit, in almost ALL cases, does not require user interaction. Yes, it includes functionality that can require user interaction, but the whole point of Metasploit is to discover and exploit vulnerabilities without user interaction. The whole idea is to be able to run code on the remote machine directly without the user knowing. A RAT is a *payload*.

Comment: @schroeder: Are you sure it's "in almost ALL cases" ? Each Metasploit's payload tutorials I come across always have the victim to click on a link to be able to success. That's why I'm surprised to hear that it's meant especially to exploit without victim's interaction. Could you give me an example or two of attacks without victim's interaction please ? 
 
You didn't clearly answer about the reason of using vulnerabilities attacks over RAT attacks (cybergate, njrat etc...). So it's because with Metasploit, you wouldn't need any victim interaction ?

Comment: @schroeder: Oh and can you confirm me that with Metasploit's attacks, you cannot perform any attack without some informations about the victim ?  (IP, adobe version etc...). Thanks.

Comment: void_in : Ok but still you can bind the RAT to a pdf.
When you say "If you are exploiting a core Windows service [...] you don't need interaction", you mean, at the very first, the victim does not have to click on a link ? To me, "user interaction" means you have to interact with the victim to make her install the trojan. And usually, it's done by making her click on something.
Were you thinking about something else ?